# How do you navigate Xamarin Forms using Prism from Master Detail to Content Page without Master Detail

Tags: xamarin, navigation, master-detail, prism-4

I am using Xamarin Forms with Prism. How do you navigate from the MasterDetail.Master to a ContentPage that is not part of the MasterDetail (that is, I don't want to just update the detail and continue to be part of the Master/Detail relationship)? The use case is like the Gmail app when you click on Settings from the Hamburger menu. It takes you out of the Master/Detail and you are now in a NavigationPage/ContentPage with a back button to get back to the MasterDetail page.

If you were not using Prism you could go to the Detail page and do a Navigation.PushAsync from there:

```
var mdp = Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
mdp.IsPresented = false;
await mdp.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new ContentPage2());
```

But I don't see how to do this using Prism navigation.

-Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Application.Current.MainPage` is a `MasterDetailPage`. Current `Detail` in the `MasterDetailPage` is `NavigationPage(new ContentPage1())`.

In your `ContentPage1`, you have 2 options to navigate to `ContentPage2`:

**Option 1:** Show `ContentPage2` in current navigation stack

You will be pushing `ContentPage2` into the same Navigation stack of `ContentPage1`. Back button in navigation bar will be added automatically.

```
// Call this code in ContentPage1
_navigationService.PushAsync("ContentPage2");
```

**Option 2:** Show `ContentPage2` modally

You are presenting the page modally and in a completely new navigation stack. You will need to add Back button in the NavigationBar and handle the click event with your own code.

```
// Call this code in ContentPage1
_navigationService.PushAsync("NavigationPage/ContentPage2", null, true);
```

Comment: Yes, option 1 is what I would like to implement. So, I will need access to the ViewModel of the detail page. I do not know the specific detail page because I am swapping a number of detail pages into the master/detail relationship. So, I am creating an interface for detail ViewModel classes that has a single method (NavigateTo(string param)) to perform navigation to the param. From the master ViewModel, I am getting to the detail page's ViewModel through the Detail.CurrentPage.BindingContext and casting to the interface and calling the NavigateTo method. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You could use MessagingCenter to notify the detail page ViewModel to do the navigation instead of casting.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful.